# Converting uploadify code from ASP.NET 4 to MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I have a ASP.NET 4 working uploadify code that upload both single and mutiple files.
I use HttpHandler to handle the upload at the server side once uploadify sends them.

How should I approach this in MVC 3?

Do I need to write different actions to handle single file vs multiple file upload?

I just need the structure of the code so that I can process the posted files at server.

Here are my code in ASP.NET 4:

```
$(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '/content/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '/content/uploadify/uploadimg.ashx', <<-- httphandler here
            'scriptData': { 'auth': auth, 'sid': sid, 'aid': '', 'pid': 0, 'multi': 1 },
            'cancelImg': '/content/uploadify/cancel.gif',
            'folder': '/content/uploadify/uploads',
            'auto': false,
            'multi': true,
            'queueSizeLimit': 10,
            'sizeLimit': 2359296,
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg',
            'fileDesc': 'Photo Files ( .jpg )',
            'displayData': 'speed',
            'expressInstall': '/content/uploadify/expressInstall.swf',
            'removeCompleted': false,
            'wmode': 'transparent',
            'hideButton': true,
            'height': 33,
            'width': 156

            , 'onSelectOnce': function (event, data) { //code omitted }

            , 'onError': function (e, fid, fo, eo) { //code omitted }

            , 'onComplete': function (e, q, f, r, d) { //code omitted }

            , 'onAllComplete': function (e, d) {
                //code omitted
            }
        });
    });


uploadimg.ashx:
public class uploadimg : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
         //code omitted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a single action -- modified from [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx).

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
    var r = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
            continue;
        string savedFileName = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
            Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

And then change your upload path with your uploadify script accordingly.

Comment: That was written for MVC 2 & may work in MVC 3 as well. I am not sure though.